# common lisp exception handling (condition and restart)

Tags: exception, common-lisp, conditional-statements, restart, condition-system

I have been read the common lisp "Practical Common Lisp" exception handling chapter for days, but I am now so confused with the samples and the explanations, in the meanwhile I tried to write some testing sample, but it didn't work as I expected, below is my testing samples.

1. Condition definition

   ```
   (define-condition evenp-error (error) 
     ((text :initarg :text :reader text)))
   ```
2. Define function that prints odd number

   ```
   (defun filter-evenp (lst)
     (dolist (x lst)
       (if (not (evenp x)) 
         (print x)
         (error 'evenp-error :text x))))
   ```
3. Restart function

   ```
   (defun skip-evenp (c) (invoke-start 'skip-evenp))
   ```
4. Restart case

   ```
   (restart-case (filter-evenp (list 1 2 3 4 5))
     (skip-evenp () nil))
   ```

All I want to do is to print all odd numbers and skip the even errors, what is wrong with my sample? anybody help? many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put your `RESTART-CASE` to where you want to restart the execution at:

```
(defun filter-evenp (lst)
  (dolist (x lst)
    (restart-case
        (if (not (evenp x))
            (print x)
            (error 'evenp-error :text x))
      (skip-evenp () nil))))
```

Then you should use `HANDLER-BIND` to handle the error:

```
(handler-bind ((evenp-error #'skip-evenp))
  (filter-evenp (list 1 2 3 4 5)))
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I am still not sure that where #'skip-evenp refer. to ?

Comment: `#'SKIP-EVENP` refers to the function by that name (that's what the `#'` means). The `HANDLER-BIND` tells it to handle any `EVENP-ERROR`s by calling the function `SKIP-EVENP`.

Comment: @user2015063 `#'` is a reader-macro: the above is equivalent to `(function skip-event)` and uses the [function](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_fn.htm) special operator to refer to the function object lexically bound to the skip-event symbol.

Comment: @jkiiski thanks very much, I finally figured it out after searched more sample via google,

Answer (score 7):

[Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html) is quite detailed but it is true that the condition system might require some time to get used to. You might be interested by Kent Pitman's articles: [Exceptional Situations in Lisp](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Exceptional-Situations-1990.html)  and [Condition Handling in the Lisp Language Family](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Condition-Handling-2001.html).

Those are referenced in [What's a condition system and why do you want one?](http://axisofeval.blogspot.fr/2011/04/whats-condition-system-and-why-do-you.html). There are also many other references lilke this [Wikibooks entry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Common_Lisp/Advanced_topics/Condition_System) or C2 wiki's [CommonLispConditionSystem](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CommonLispConditionSystem) entry.

#### Defining a restart

A [`RESTART-CASE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_rst_ca.htm) basically says:

> *I am going to execute this form and I don't care if it signals a condition or not. But if it does and you want to recover from that situation, here are different ways I can work around the problem (retry, ignore, etc.).*

You generally cannot say how to recover from an error in the code being called at the call point. In other words, it is `filter-evenp` which should wrap the code with a `restart-case` in-order to provide alternative paths. For your example, it would be sufficient to use [`CERROR`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cerror.htm), which signals an error while establishing a `CONTINUE` restart.

```
(if (evenp x)
  (cerror "Ignore even number" 'evenp-error :text x) 
  (print x))
```

As an exercise you can try to replace `(cerror ...)` with an explicit `restart-case` construct.

Then, if you test your code, you should see your debugger pop up and show you the `CONTINUE` restart. If you defined your own restart, you can name it differently.

#### Invoking the restart

In your `skip-evenp` function, you were invoking a restart that was not established a at this point, and I think you were confused with `skip-evenp` naming both a restart and a function.

What you should do is *handle* the error by *invoking* the restart.

Here, you want the code that signals an error to continue, so you really don't want to unwind the execution stack. That's why you have to use [`HANDLER-BIND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_handle.htm).

```
(handler-bind ((evenp-error (lambda (e) (invoke-restart 'continue))))
  (filter-evenp '(1 2 3 4)))
1
3
```

You can of course extract the anonymous lambda into a custom function, like you did.

Comment: the solution you provide the exactly what I want, but I am still confused with the restart stuff, let me try to find some more material to figure it out, thanks!

Comment: @user2015063 If the user is useful, consider accepting it with the green checkmark. I'll add more references if that can help you.